# kendo-dropdownlist hangs Chrome

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I'm using Telerik Angular2 "kendo-dropdownlist" component.

I have been experiencing excessive CPU with Chrome but I have not been able to identify the issue or issues. However, I just experienced it with the "kendo-dropdownlist".

Here's and example of the code

```
<kendo-dropdownlist class="mr-sm-1 col-11"
formControlName="rankGrade"
[data]="MilitaryRanks"
[defaultItem]="{ rank: 'Select rank', value: null }"
[textField]="'rank'"
[valueField]="'rank'"
[valuePrimitive]="true">
</kendo-dropdownlist>
```

For now it seems to happens on pages where I have multiple "kendo-dropdownlist".

Has anyone experience this?

Chrome version Version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit)

Thank you

Comment: On Kendo UI site around http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/ there are some demos that also can be copied  for editing to http://plnkr.co/.Could you create [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) there or anywhere else? It is hard to guess but only this small piece of code

Comment: I have noticed this as well; in my instance, I have a "kendo-dropdownlist" inside of a "kendo-dialog" and it freezes ONLY IF I have the Chrome Dev Tools open. If the dev tools are closed, it works just fine. I have not figured out why, either.

Comment: Do you have some more code to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I'm no longer getting the hanging with the latest release of the Kendo components.